# Docker image just contain software without OS

Tags: docker, dockerfile, rhel

I have a PROD environment running on RHEL 7 server. I want to use docker for deployment. I want to package all the software and apps in a Docker image, without a base OS. Because I don't want to add an additional layer on top of RHEL. Also, I could not find an official base image for RHEL. Is that possible?

I see some old posts mentioned about "FROM scratch" but looks it does not work in the latest version of Docker -- 1.12.5.

If this is impossible, any suggestions for this?

Comment: Are you trying to package all of the apps in an environment into a single container? This usually is bad practice in docker as they recommend a single service in each container.

Comment: Either you compile your entire app into a self-contained executable with zero dependencies --or-- you use docker as intended with a base os.

Comment: I want to separate my apps (currently just one app) from the OS and other dependencies. My problem is that I don't want to have my base image has the "FROM: RHEL" to introduce an additional layer on top of my host OS.

Comment: you can always use something super minimal as base image (for example alpine). When docker starts a container it's only starting one process. If your app is in Java then it will start JVM. What you need to provide in image is JVM with all external libs it requires. So using Ubuntu or RHEL as base makes sense only for build process (known pkg repos or versions), when app starts it will use only libs it needs and ignore the rest of image.

Answer (score 1):

Docker is designed to also abstract the OS dependencies - that is what it has been build for. Beside it also encapsulates the runtime, memory and things, it specifically is used as a extreme-better variant of chroot ( lets say chroot on ultra-steroids ).

It seems like you neither want the runtime seperation nor the OS layer seperation ( dependencies ) - thus docker makes absolutely no sense for you.

Deploying with docker the is not "simple" or simpler as using other tools. You can use capistrano or, probably something like https://www.habitat.sh/ which actually does not require a software to be bundled in docker containers to be "deployable", it also works on barebones and uses its own packaging format. Thus you have a state-of-the-art deployment solution, and with habitat, you can later even upgrade using docker-containers.